# Simplifying $\frac{\frac12\sqrt{w^2+d^2}}{\sqrt{\frac14(w^2+d^2)+(h-k)^2}}$ to $\sqrt{\frac{w^2+d^2}{d^2+4(h-k)^2+w^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, fractions

I'm getting to the point in an example question where I get the answer:

$$\frac{\frac12\sqrt{w^2+d^2}}{\sqrt{\frac14(w^2+d^2)+(h-k)^2}}\quad\to\quad\sqrt{\frac{w^2+d^2}{d^2+4(h-k)^2+w^2}}$$

I am having a mental block on how the answer simplified into the second expression.

Comment: **Hint :** $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$

Comment: Warning, that hint is only valid when $a$ and $b$ are both positive real numbers.  In your case, there is no danger since everything involved is the square of a real number and so non-negative.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks a lot. I'm just unsure how the 1/2 and 1/4 are manipulated once the root is taken of the fraction?

Comment: **Second hint :** $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$, and $\sqrt{1/4} = 1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the numerator by $2$ and the denominator by $\sqrt{4}$.

That does not change the value, since $2=\sqrt4$, and remember that $\sqrt4\sqrt s=\sqrt{4s}$.

Comment: So the fraction is multiplied by 2/sqrt(4) ?

Comment: Yes, $\dfrac{\frac12\sqrt{w^2+d^2}}{\sqrt{\frac14(w^2+d^2)+(h-k)^2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{w^2+d^2}}{\sqrt{w^2+d^2+4(h-k)^2}} $

Comment: I'm just really struggling to see where the 4 in the 4(h-k)^2 comes from